# how to setting chart js customization

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to use chart.js in my websites. I am successfully implemented with the code below

```
    var doughnutData = [
        {
            value: 30,
            color:"#f91942",
        },
        {
            value : 50,
            color : "#0b7bb5"
        },
        {
            value : 120,
            color : "#4D5360"
        }

    ];

    var labels = [
        'Red',
        'Yellow',
        'Blue'
    ];


    var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

</script>`
```

The result is like this

[image]

Now I want to know that is there anywhere to make the column show the number when mouse hover and adding a label for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add label with your data to show it in the tooltip

```
var doughnutData = [{
    value: 30,
    color: "#f91942",
    label: 'Red'
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#0b7bb5",
    label: 'Yellow'
}, {
    value: 120,
    color: "#4D5360",
    label: 'Blue'
}];
```

This will display tooltip with default template

```
<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>
```

Which show like

> Red: 30

You can change the template using **tooltipTemplate** key, like below

```
var options: {
  tooltipTemplate: "This value is -> <%= value %>"
};
var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(data, options);
```

This will give you

> This value is -> 50